# How to exclude zero values from an array when calculating average?

Tags: javascript, arrays, average

I'm trying to exclude the "0" values from an array to get a better average result.

my array is: [0, 0, 0, 0, 80, 90, 100, 0]

```
function clacGPA(gradeData) {
  var sum, avg = 0;

  if (gradeData.length) {
    sum = gradeData.reduce(function (a, b) {
      return a + b;
    });
    avg = sum / gradeData.length;
  }
  document.getElementById('gpa').innerText = avg.toFixed(2);
}


My expected result should be:
avg = 80+90+100 / 3
```

Comment: Create a new array using the function `filter` just for getting the length it's not ok.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just filter out 0 values first:

```js
clacGPA([0, 0, 0, 0, 80, 90, 100, 0]);
function clacGPA(gradeData) {
  const filtered = gradeData.filter(item => item !== 0);
  const sum = filtered.reduce((a, b) => a + b);
  const avg = sum / filtered.length;
  console.log(avg);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the function `reduce` with an accumulator which stores the count and the sum.

```js
let arr = [0, 0, 0, 0, 80, 90, 100, 0];
let result = arr.reduce((a, c) => {
  if (c !== 0) {
    a.count++;
    a.sum += c;
  }
  
  return a;
}, {count: 0, sum: 0});

if (result.count) console.log(result.sum / result.count);
```